# EditTextCell FieldUpdater width

Tags: java, gwt

How can I set the width of the text-box when the field is editing?

```
EditTextCell febCell = new EditTextCell();
Column<DTO, String> febColumn = new Column<DTO, String>(febCell){
    @Override
    public String getValue(DTO object) {
        return (String.valueOf(object.getFeb()));
    }
};
febColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<DTO, String>() {
    public void update(int index, DTO object, String value) {
        System.out.println("index="+index+" resourceId="+object.getId()+" feb="+value);
    }
});
febColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LOCALE_END);
cellTable.addColumn(febColumn, "Feb");
cellTable.setColumnWidth(febColumn, 3, Unit.PCT);
```

Everything is working well, but when I do click on the editable field a very big text box appears. So, how can I customize this widget for editing the data?

If I do set the width in PX instead of PCT like

```
cellTable.setColumnWidth(febColumn, 25, Unit.PX);
```

the cell does not explode while editing, but the inner text box still has the same long width and a long string value hides out behind the right side.

OK. Probably I need reinvent to the wheel for each kind of EditTextCell like that:

```
MyEditTextCell extends AbstractEditableCell<String, MyEditTextCell.ViewData> ...
interface MyTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\" size=\"{1}\" maxlength=\"{1}\" style=\"{2}\"></input>")
    SafeHtml input(String value, Integer maxLength, String style);
}
...
@Override public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
                             String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {...

sb.append(template.input(text, maxLegth, style));
```

And use the widget like that:

```
MyEditTextCell febCell = new MyEditTextCell(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance(), 4, "width:35px;");
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Good question. Actually, I need same feature. But I need make it bigger. Can I do it without reimplementing `EditTextCell`? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. How do I resize the EditTextCell?

Comment: @user491753, I just copy/paste `EditTextCell`. Than, add size argument to template. Than add size setter to my class. And use setted value in render method. If it doesn't clear, write here and  I will provide full source code.

Comment: I tried running the code for EditTextCell.java..I got it from (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/EditTextCell.java?r=9278) but it has lots of error. I pasted the code under your stuff. I understand what you suggested but the code has lots of error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user491753, I post workable solution as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Solution with reimplementation. Put attention at `setInputWidth` method.

```
public class JustInPlaceEditCell extends AbstractEditableCell<String, JustInPlaceEditCell.ViewData> {

    interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
        @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\" size=\"{1}\"></input>")
        SafeHtml input(String value, int size);
    }

    /**
     * The view data object used by this cell. We need to store both the text and
     * the state because this cell is rendered differently in edit mode. If we did
     * not store the edit state, refreshing the cell with view data would always
     * put us in to edit state, rendering a text box instead of the new text
     * string.
     */
    static class ViewData {

        private boolean isEditing;

        /**
         * If true, this is not the first edit.
         */
        private boolean isEditingAgain;

        /**
         * Keep track of the original value at the start of the edit, which might be
         * the edited value from the previous edit and NOT the actual value.
         */
        private String original;

        private String text;

        /**
         * Construct a new ViewData in editing mode.
         *
         * @param text the text to edit
         */
        public ViewData(String text) {
            this.original = text;
            this.text = text;
            this.isEditing = true;
            this.isEditingAgain = false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == null) {
                return false;
            }
            ViewData vd = (ViewData) o;
            return equalsOrBothNull(original, vd.original)
                    && equalsOrBothNull(text, vd.text) && isEditing == vd.isEditing
                    && isEditingAgain == vd.isEditingAgain;
        }

        public String getOriginal() {
            return original;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return original.hashCode() + text.hashCode()
                    + Boolean.valueOf(isEditing).hashCode() * 29
                    + Boolean.valueOf(isEditingAgain).hashCode();
        }

        public boolean isEditing() {
            return isEditing;
        }

        public boolean isEditingAgain() {
            return isEditingAgain;
        }

        public void setEditing(boolean isEditing) {
            boolean wasEditing = this.isEditing;
            this.isEditing = isEditing;

            // This is a subsequent edit, so start from where we left off.
            if (!wasEditing && isEditing) {
                isEditingAgain = true;
                original = text;
            }
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }


        private boolean equalsOrBothNull(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return (o1 == null) ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2);
        }
    }

    private static Template template;

    private int inputWidth = 20;

    public int getInputWidth() {
        return inputWidth;
    }

    public void setInputWidth(int inputWidth) {
        this.inputWidth = inputWidth;
    }

    private final SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer;

    /**
     * Construct a new EditTextCell that will use a
     * {@link com.google.gwt.text.shared.SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer}.
     */
    public JustInPlaceEditCell() {
        this(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance());
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new EditTextCell that will use a given {@link SafeHtmlRenderer}.
     *
     * @param renderer a {@link SafeHtmlRenderer SafeHtmlRenderer<String>} instance
     */
    public JustInPlaceEditCell(SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer) {
        super("click", "keyup", "keydown", "blur");
        if (template == null) {
            template = GWT.create(Template.class);
        }
        if (renderer == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("renderer == null");
        }
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEditing(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
        ViewData viewData = getViewData(context.getKey());
        return viewData == null ? false : viewData.isEditing();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
                               NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        Object key = context.getKey();
        ViewData viewData = getViewData(key);
        if (viewData != null && viewData.isEditing()) {
            // Handle the edit event.
            editEvent(context, parent, value, viewData, event, valueUpdater);
        } else {
            String type = event.getType();
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            boolean enterPressed = "keyup".equals(type)
                    && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER;
            if ("click".equals(type) || enterPressed) {
                // Go into edit mode.
                if (viewData == null) {
                    viewData = new ViewData(value);
                    setViewData(key, viewData);
                } else {
                    viewData.setEditing(true);
                }
                edit(context, parent, value);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        // Get the view data.
        Object key = context.getKey();
        ViewData viewData = getViewData(key);
        if (viewData != null && !viewData.isEditing() && value != null
                && value.equals(viewData.getText())) {
            clearViewData(key);
            viewData = null;
        }

        if (viewData != null) {
            String text = viewData.getText();
            SafeHtml html = renderer.render(text);
            if (viewData.isEditing()) {
                // Note the template will not treat SafeHtml specially
                sb.append(template.input(html.asString(), inputWidth));
            } else {
                // The user pressed enter, but view data still exists.
                sb.append(html);
            }
        } else if (value != null) {
            SafeHtml html = renderer.render(value);
            sb.append(html);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean resetFocus(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
        if (isEditing(context, parent, value)) {
            getInputElement(parent).focus();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the cell to edit mode.
     *
     * @param context the {@link Context} of the cell
     * @param parent  the parent element
     * @param value   the current value
     */
    protected void edit(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
        setValue(context, parent, value);
        InputElement input = getInputElement(parent);
        input.focus();
        input.select();
    }

    /**
     * Convert the cell to non-edit mode.
     *
     * @param context the context of the cell
     * @param parent  the parent Element
     * @param value   the value associated with the cell
     */
    private void cancel(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
        clearInput(getInputElement(parent));
        setValue(context, parent, value);
    }

    /**
     * Clear selected from the input element. Both Firefox and IE fire spurious
     * onblur events after the input is removed from the DOM if selection is not
     * cleared.
     *
     * @param input the input element
     */
    private native void clearInput(Element input) /*-{
        if (input.selectionEnd)
            input.selectionEnd = input.selectionStart;
        else if ($doc.selection)
            $doc.selection.clear();
    }-*/;

    /**
     * Commit the current value.
     *
     * @param context      the context of the cell
     * @param parent       the parent Element
     * @param viewData     the {@link ViewData} object
     * @param valueUpdater the {@link ValueUpdater}
     */
    private void commit(Context context, Element parent, ViewData viewData,
                        ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        String value = updateViewData(parent, viewData, false);
        clearInput(getInputElement(parent));
        setValue(context, parent, viewData.getOriginal());
        if (valueUpdater != null) {
            valueUpdater.update(value);
        }
    }

    private void editEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
                           ViewData viewData, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        String type = event.getType();
        boolean keyUp = "keyup".equals(type);
        boolean keyDown = "keydown".equals(type);
        if (keyUp || keyDown) {
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            if (keyUp && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                // Commit the change.
                commit(context, parent, viewData, valueUpdater);
            } else if (keyUp && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) {
                // Cancel edit mode.
                String originalText = viewData.getOriginal();
                if (viewData.isEditingAgain()) {
                    viewData.setText(originalText);
                    viewData.setEditing(false);
                } else {
                    setViewData(context.getKey(), null);
                }
                cancel(context, parent, value);
            } else {
                // Update the text in the view data on each key.
                updateViewData(parent, viewData, true);
            }
        } else if ("blur".equals(type)) {
            // Commit the change. Ensure that we are blurring the input element and
            // not the parent element itself.
            EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
            if (Element.is(eventTarget)) {
                Element target = Element.as(eventTarget);
                if ("input".equals(target.getTagName().toLowerCase())) {
                    commit(context, parent, viewData, valueUpdater);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the input element in edit mode.
     */
    private InputElement getInputElement(Element parent) {
        return parent.getFirstChild().<InputElement>cast();
    }

    /**
     * Update the view data based on the current value.
     *
     * @param parent    the parent element
     * @param viewData  the {@link ViewData} object to update
     * @param isEditing true if in edit mode
     * @return the new value
     */
    private String updateViewData(Element parent, ViewData viewData,
                                  boolean isEditing) {
        InputElement input = (InputElement) parent.getFirstChild();
        String value = input.getValue();
        viewData.setText(value);
        viewData.setEditing(isEditing);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. Now.what If I want to pass the width as an argument when creating a JustInPlaceEditCell, then what do I need to change?

Comment: @user491753 you should add constructor that would take `inputWidth`. Or just use setter after creation

Comment: You have an error there -- instead of value=\"{0}\" you need to have {0} inbetween the textarea tags, otherwise the value won't be shown

Comment: @Vladimir I'll check it tomorrow. But I'm pretty sure about it correctness.

Comment: @StasKurilin -- sorry, I'm wrong -- my comment was meant for the below answer, where he uses a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. Use a text area element instead of input type="text". I started with the source of EditTextCell and inserted textarea elements instead of input at the appropriate places. See below for code

```
public class TextAreaEditCell extends
    AbstractEditableCell<String, TextAreaEditCell.ViewData> {

interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<textarea tabindex=\"-1\" rows=\"{1}\" cols=\"{2}\" >{0}</textarea>")
    SafeHtml input(String value, Integer rows, Integer cols);
}
... 
private int rows, cols;

/**
 * Construct a new EditTextCell that will use a
 * {@link SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer}.
 */
public TextAreaEditCell() {
    this(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance(), 1, 20);
}

/**
 * Construct a new EditTextCell that will use a given
 * {@link SafeHtmlRenderer} to render the value when not in edit mode.
 * 
 * @param renderer
 *            a {@link SafeHtmlRenderer SafeHtmlRenderer<String>} instance
 */
public TextAreaEditCell(SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer, int r, int c) {
    super("click", "keyup", "keydown", "blur");
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
...
} else if ("blur".equals(type)) {
        // Commit the change. Ensure that we are blurring the input element
        // and
        // not the parent element itself.
        EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
        if (Element.is(eventTarget)) {
            Element target = Element.as(eventTarget);
            if ("textarea".equals(target.getTagName().toLowerCase())) {
...
/**
 * Get the input element in edit mode.
 */
private TextAreaElement getInputElement(Element parent) {
    return parent.getFirstChild().<TextAreaElement> cast();
}
...
    private String updateViewData(Element parent, ViewData viewData,
        boolean isEditing) {
    TextAreaElement input = (TextAreaElement) parent.getFirstChild();
    // InputElement input = (InputElement) parent.getFirstChild();
...
```

Comment: I can do this stuff with specifying size on input element. The task is to do this without copy/paste or reimplementing current widgets.